# Python only sort sub-sequences in a sequence

Tags: python, string, sorting

My data looks like:

```
{12,} {13,} {10,}
{16,} {17, 15,} {22,}
{27,} {28,24,29,} {28,} {28,}
```

Each line is a sequence. For each line, if multiple numbers occur in {  }, I want to sort them in each bracket(ascending sort ), while keeping the order of the rest. At last, I want to remove the brackets. So I want my output to be like this:

```
12, 13, 10
16, 15, 17, 22
27, 24, 28, 29, 28, 28
```

My thought was converting each line into a list, but then I was totally stuck.

Comment: From the notation, your data look like `set`s, which are unordered collections rather than sequences. Can you provide more details about what your data actually are?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. This is actually what my data looks like, I just changed the numbers in it. It's a txt file, just a matter of format. The data is a time series data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-liner using `re.sub` function.

```
>>> s = """{12,} {13,} {10,}
{16,} {17, 15,} {22,}
{27,} {28,24,29,} {28,} {28,}"""
>>> print(re.sub(r'(?<=\d) +(?=\d)', ', ', re.sub(r'\{[^}]*\}', lambda m: ', '.join(sorted(re.findall(r'\d+', m.group(0)), key=lambda x: int(x))), s)))
12, 13, 10
16, 15, 17, 22
27, 24, 28, 29, 28, 28
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested list comprehension: `[[f for s in sequences for f in sorted(s)] for sequences in lines]`

Comment: Might want to include an `ast.literal_eval()` in there since the input is a text file.

Comment: Sorry, It doesn't work if I set `lines='{12,} {13,} {10,}'`.